# Angular 6 - Populate table dynamically

Tags: html-table, angular6, ngfor

I am trying to fill a table dynamically but can't figure out why this isn't working!

Here I get my json, where I save the array of objects in customerArray.

```
export class AllCustomersComponent implements OnInit {
customerArray: any;


    constructor(private http : HttpClient ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
         this.http.get('http://www.mocky.io/v2/5be715ce2e00008a0016945e')
        .subscribe((data) => {
           this.customerArray = data;
          console.log(customerArray);
      }
    }
}
```

here I am trying to populate the table with the said array.

```
<table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">First</th>
            <th scope="col">Last</th>
            <th scope="col">Age</th>
            <th scope="col">Edit</th>
            <th scope="col">Delete</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>46</td>
            <td><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></td>
            <td><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td *ngFor="let customer of customerArray">{{customer}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

but my table just render this:

```
[object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object]
```

Comment: `console.log(customerArray);` where is `customerArray` defined? Or should it be `this.customerArray`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your customer is an object, how should angular know what to render for it?

What you may need is something like this:

```
<tr *ngFor="let customer of customerArray">
   <td>{{customer.firstname}}</td>
   <td>{{customer.lastname}}</td>
   <td>{{customer.age}}</td>
   <td>{{customer.whatever}}</td>
   <td>{{customer.whatever}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: this makes a lot of sense and it is working now! thank you!

Comment: @kontenurban You should mark the answer as correct if it worked for you...